# Connect and Disconnect USB Cable to iPhone using IOS programming

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, eaaccessory

I am developing a iPhone app like **" Eject device"** on computer. which means, when I connect USB cable for  connecting to computer, this application just disconnect that connection by a single Click. I was googled about this, and I got some idea about `EAAccessoryManager` . this `EAAccessoryManager` only for notification. when USB cable connects or disconnect it can notify to the user.  But I need to disconnect connection programmatically . is there any API or Tutorial available for this ? Kindly help me please.

Comment: You should never need to eject a USB cable since it doesn't cache data like USB drives on computers. It's only needed for those because they loose power the moment you unplug (and loses cached data) but the iPhone stays on after being unplugged so nothing will be lost. Also, `EAAccessoryManager` is for connecting your own hardware to the iPhone AFAIK, not for USB...

Comment: @jjv360 : thank you for your comment. yes I know 'EAAccessoryManager' is not for this. I just mentioned that, I was googled and I haven't found anything other than this. anyhow, do you have any idea about my question friend ?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at IOKit. I believe IOKit works with USB device both on iOS and OS X.

You may be interested to take a look at these link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOKit.framework

Also, there is very good book on iOS/OS X kernel and I believe there is a whole chapter regarding IOKit:

[http://www.amazon.com/Mac-OS-iOS-Internals-Apples/dp/1118057651](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118057651)

Comment: Thank you Victor, you given me a great idea. thanks a lot. I am looking at those documents now.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the private API for the iOS Frameworks in https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks, but I don't think that this capability is present. The reason I think this is because there is no reason to want to do this from the iPhone, and therefore no reason for Apple to include it in the API.

Comment: The question is explicitly tagged with "jailbreak" and "iphone-privateapi" which means that he is looking for some solution which won't be distributed to AppStore.

Comment: I included information about the private API just for that purpose. I figured that if somebody else who wanted to do this on a non-jailbroken device came upon this question, they would find an answer.

Comment: iOS is built on top of the same kernel as OSX. Both of these operation system are capable of managing external devices. So, they are definitely have code to connect/disconnect them.